# How to set a max column length for streamlit-aggrid

Tags: python, ag-grid, streamlit

If I have a really long column entry that takes up most of the table (like below) how do I set the table options such that it gets truncated?

```
import streamlit as st
from st_aggrid import AgGrid
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'some short column': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
                   'some long column': ['all column and no spacing makes coder a dull boy '
                                        'all column and no spacing makes coder a dull boy '
                                        'all column and no spacing makes coder a dull boy '
                                        'all column and no spacing makes coder a dull boy '
                                        'all column and no spacing makes coder a dull boy '
                                        'all column and no spacing makes coder a dull boy '
                                        'all column and no spacing makes coder a dull boy '
                                        'all column and no spacing makes coder a dull boy ', 'two', 'three'],
                   'some other column': ['one', 'two', 'three'],
                   'some other column 2': ['one', 'two', 'three']})

AgGrid(df)
```

[image]

Edit:

```
AgGrid(df, fit_columns_on_grid_load=True)
```

Works for this example but my actual df has > 20 columns, and this causes the columns to be too crunched together to read.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the fit_columns_on_grid_load param, this is False by default.

```
AgGrid(df, fit_columns_on_grid_load=True)
```

Comment: This is a solution for the above example, I'm sorry I oversimplified. If I do that then all of the columns crunch together to be illegible. (theres ~20). I will edit post to reflect this.

Comment: I found a solution using your input, if you update the response will mark it as the solution!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for this combination! I had to add the `fit_columns_on_grid` in a separate configuration line though, so:

```
gb = GridOptionsBuilder.from_dataframe(df)
gb.configure_default_column(min_column_width=150)
interactive_table = AgGrid(df, gridOptions=gb.build(), fit_columns_on_grid_load=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Combined with @ferdy's answer. If I use:

```
gb = GridOptionsBuilder.from_dataframe(df, min_column_width=30)
AgGrid(df, gridOptions=gb.build(), fit_columns_on_grid_load=True)
```

Then it works securely.